# Python TensorFlow rewrite classic for loop into tf.while_loop

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, nested-loops

I have a function

```
def multivariate_data(dataset, target, start_index, end_index, history_size,
                      target_size, step, single_step=False):
  data = []
  labels = []
  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size
  #print(history_size)
  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i, step)
    data.append(dataset[indices])
    if single_step:
      labels.append(target[i+target_size])
    else:
      labels.append(target[i:i+target_size])
  return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

I would like to make my calculations on GPU. But only tensor operations can be run on GPU. So I need to rewrite my function.
for loops must be changed to tf.while_loop.
All my numpy arrays mustbe changed into Tensors.
How can i rewrite my function an for loops into tf.while_loop?

Answer (score 0):

II have not tested using a GPU and I have assumed the input data is a rank 1 tensor and removed some parameters. I am not using the *labels*. There is also no exception handling but this can be refactored.

I am concatenating the tensors to 'append' to self._data but there are other efficient ways to 'append'.

```
            self._data = tf.concat([self._data,tf.gather(dataset, tf.range(1, 3, 1))],0)
```

This line just shows that a range can be used to pick values from a tensor to append to another. Exceptions are not handled as the data is fixed.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    
    
class MultiVariate():
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = None
        self._labels = None

    def multivariate_data(self,
                          dataset,
                          start_index,
                          end_index,
                          history_size,
                          target_size,
                          single_step=False):
         start_index = start_index + history_size
         tf.print("end_index ", end_index)
         tf.print("start_index ", start_index)
         if self._data is None:
             self._data = tf.cast(tf.Variable(tf.reshape((), (0,))),dtype=tf.int32)
         if self._labels is None:
             self._labels = tf.cast(tf.Variable(tf.reshape((), (0,))),dtype=tf.int32)
         if end_index is None:
            end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

         def cond(i, j):
             return tf.less(i, j)

         def body(i, j):
             #A range of values are gathered
             self._data = tf.concat([self._data,[tf.gather(dataset, i)]],0)
             if ( i == start_index ): #Showing how A range of values are gathered and appended
                self._data = tf.concat([self._data,tf.gather(dataset, tf.range(1, 3, 1))],0)
             return tf.add( i , 1 ), j

         _,_ = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [start_index,end_index],shape_invariants=[start_index.get_shape(), end_index.get_shape()])

         return self._data

mv = MultiVariate()
d =    mv.multivariate_data(
                      tf.constant([1,88,99,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
                      tf.constant(2),
                      tf.constant(8),
                      tf.constant(1),
                      tf.constant(2),
                      tf.constant(2))
print("print ",d)
```

> print  tf.Tensor([ 4 88 99  5  6  7  8], shape=(7,), dtype=int32)